# CSS horizontal menu items on right overlap when window resized

Tags: css, position, css-float, window-resize

I have searched but have been unable to find a solution to this.

I have a CSS horizontal menu with the navigation menu aligned to the left and the toolbar items aligned to the right. It looks fine when the browser window is expanded, but when it is resized down, the right-hand toolbar overlaps the nav menu items on the left. Obviously this is because I have positioned it right but I'm unsure how to get around this. Is it possible to prevent the toolbar from overlapping and instead hide and produce a horizontal scroll bar?

Please see my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e9etC/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="navcontainer">
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">AAAAA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BBBBB</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">xxxxx</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">xxxx</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">dddd</a></li>
                <li><a class="menuparent" href="#">cccccc</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">1111</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">2222</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">333</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">CCCCC</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
                <li><a class="menuparent" href="#">SubMenu</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">SubSubMenu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SubSubMenu</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">DDDDD</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">EEEE</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">GGGGG</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="toolbar">
    <ul>
        <li class="currentclient"><a title="Most recently selected client" href="#">1234567: John Doe</a></li>
        <li>Client Search</li>
        <li><input name="cpc" title="Search by client code, names, email address, phone numbers or CSN." id="cpc" style="width: 150px;" type="text"/></li>
        <li><input name="btnCP" class="inputbutton" id="btnCP" type="button" value="Search"/></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body
{
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
}

#navcontainer
{
    position: fixed;        
    top: 14px;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    height: 28px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#navcontainer, #menu ul ul, #menu ul ul ul
{
    border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-left: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-right: 1px solid #808080;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
}

#menu, #toolbar{

    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    position: absolute;
}
#menu ul, #toolbar ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#menu li, #toolbar li{
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    white-space: nowrap;
} 

#menu li a, #toolbar li a{
    height: 28px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height: 28px;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
} 

#menu ul ul li a, #menu ul ul ul li a
{
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

#menu li a:hover{
    background-color: #A9A9A9;
    color: #fff;
} 
#menu ul ul, #menu ul ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#menu ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: -1px;
}

#menu ul li:hover > ul, #menu ul ul li:hover ul{
    visibility:visible;
}
#menu > ul > li > a {
    text-align:center;
}

#menu > ul, #toolbar > ul { 
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#menu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #808080;
  margin: 0 -3px 0 0;
}
#menu ul li:first-child
{
    border-left: none;
}

#menu  a.menuparent
{
    background-image: url(greyarrow.gif);
    background-position: right center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#toolbar
{
    right: 3px;
}

#toolbar > ul > li
{
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
#toolbar .currentclient a {
    color: #1B70E0;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.inputbutton
{
    border: solid 1px #8a9ab2;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-top: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 22px;
    background-color: #c6d2e7;
    color: #2a3341;
}
```

Comment: Giving #menu li, #toolbar li an explicit width seems to fix the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is because you've specified `position: absolute` for your elements. Changing definition of following rules will fix your issue **[Checkout this Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FZvru/)**

```
#menu, #toolbar{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 80%;
}

#toolbar{
    padding-right: 3px;
    text-align: right;
}
```